# how to improve my coding standards to meet senior developer standards

Tags: reactjs

I just recently finished a tech test for a company applying for a frontend developer working in react and I was rejected with no feedback. So I was wondering what I could have done better and improved for next time. I've just recently tried to apply for seniors frontend roles. Here is the test they gave me and what I produced.

Here is the description of their test.

```
Create a component as a Form Control according to this design
The control should accept a label
The control should accept a validation function with configurable error message
The control can be incorporated inside a <form> and the selected option pushed up to the form.
The control should fire an event on change

Use the component you made in the previous step to create a form according to this design
Call this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users to populate list of the users. name should be displayed while id should be saved as the value in the form.
Add the required validation with the Please select a user error message.
Add 2 text fields, one for title and one for body both with required validation. (Don't worry about matching the design for the text fields.)
On submit of the form create a new post by sending the data to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. The request interface will look like
{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar",
  "userId": 1
}
```

This is what I produced:

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-thunder-322xi?file=/src/components/FormComponent.js

I am aware it could have been better but there was a time limit and there was no feedback provided so I don't know where I went wrong. Could someone look through it please and see if it aligns with their instructions and where it could be improved.

Comment: one thing is the error messages don't go away when the inputs are valid & the form is submitted - but i guess this is more on the ux side - might have been a factor though

Comment: I posted some improvements below. Check out, this may help you :)

Answer (score 2):

I went through your code and may have found some codes which I may have implemented a little differently. I am not sure if this is the best coding standard but may have gone like this.

1. I see a lot of useStates declared there(7 declarations). I might have group some related states together. I have given an example for reference below. Using too many declarations may not be good in some cases.
2. The handleChange function  `(const handleTitleChange = (ev) => setTitle(ev.target.value);)` can be improved. The way handled here is repeating for every input. So, if I have 10 inputs, there will be 10 lines for handleChange function. I gave a better way of handling change in my example. **Remember to put the same 'name' attribute in the input field and the state.** This code will save you a lot of time in future handling onChange and also clean code
3. I see you use 'id' attribute to refer to DOM elements in the form. This is good for vanilla JS but in React, it is preferred not to use. There is a better way in react called creating a reference, i.e. React.createRef(). This provides an easy reference to the DOM elements. Please refer to my example below.
4. The validation handling method can be improved. Code in example.
5. I see the error message does not go away once you fill content. So, this needs to be changed.

I have managed to come up with another way to implement which is totally dependent on states for form validation handling.

**CODE WITH CREATE REF** Don't mind the CSS classes, I used bootstrap

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title: '',
    body: '',
  })

  const titleRef = React.createRef()
  const bodyRef = React.createRef()

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput({ ...input, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const onHandleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input.title ? titleRef.current.innerHTML = '' : titleRef.current.innerHTML = 'Please add a title';
    input.body ? bodyRef.current.innerHTML = '' : bodyRef.current.innerHTML = 'Please add a body';
    if (!input.title || !input.body) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log('Submit your form');
  }

  return (
    <div className="container py-5">
      <form onSubmit={onHandleSubmit}>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value={input.title} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        <p ref={titleRef} style={{ color: 'red' }}></p>

        <label>Body</label>
        <input type="text" name="body" value={input.body} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        <p ref={bodyRef} style={{ color: 'red' }}></p>

        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

**CODE WITH STATES FOR VALIDATION**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title: '',
    body: '',
    titleError: '',
    bodyError: '',
  })

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput({ ...input, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const onHandleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInput({
      ...input,
      titleError: input.title ? '': 'Please add a title',
      bodyError: input.body ? '': 'Please add a body', 
    })
    console.log(input);
    if (!input.title || !input.body) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log('Submit your form');
  }

  return (
    <div className="container py-5">
      <form onSubmit={onHandleSubmit}>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value={input.title} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{input.titleError}</p>

        <label>Body</label>
        <input type="text" name="body" value={input.body} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{input.bodyError}</p>

        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

P.S. There will be much better ways to handle according to the scenario, but this may help you in some way.

**EDIT:**
Adding Radio button to select the user.
userId added to state

```
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title: '',
    body: '',
    titleError: '',
    bodyError: '',
    userId: '',
  })
```

Radio select for users.

```
 <div>
      <input type="radio" name="userId" value="1" id="1"
        checked={input.userId === "1"} onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <label htmlFor="1">User 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="userId" value="2" id="2"
        checked={input.userId === "2"} onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <label htmlFor="2">User 2</label>
    </div>
```

The same onChange handler will work for the radio select also. I see you use the response from useFetch to render the users. You can use same map logic to render this radio by setting the fields. Set the `value` and `id` attribute to user id from response and so on.

Comment: Great answer I went for the low hanging fruit this is much more detailed and in-depth.

Comment: Thank you! this is a great answer, I will be following this advice for my next task.

Comment: I do have a question though, this method works well for inputs but how would this work for buttons for example, like the one I provided in the example. Buttons have no inputs so how would I have improved the button function

Comment: You are welcome, Happy to help. Buttons work on onClick event to perform an action, so it's better you define a different handler for setting the state. For your given problem above, I might have gone with a radio select or a dropdown. It will make it much easier and lesser code. I have added the code for the radio button-select in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One immediate issue I found is a console error.

Production quality code from a Sr. level developer should not be doing this. I would expect to see errors in console if a bug was found or dealing with some edge case.

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop` buttonSelected`of type`boolean`supplied to`Button`, expected` string`.
in Button (at FormComponent.js:21)

```
in FormComponent (at App.js:8)

in div (at App.js:7)

in App (at src/index.js:9)

in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)`
```

I found this in the console just browsing to the link you shared. There are other things to clean up but this is the most obvious thing I've found so far.